# Tibetan and Devanagari ligatures not getting stacked properly using iText

Tags: itext, ligature, indic

I tried to output some Unicode text using both iText-2.1.7 and iText-5.1.3.

While Devanagari characters got stacked properly, I am unable to see Tibetan characters properly stacked.

In stead, each character is occupying a separate space. I tried with BaseFonts both ARIALUNI.TTF and TibMachUni-1.901b.ttf but without success.

Googling gave me a [post of 2009](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Using-Unicode-characters-0f71-0fbc-td2147545.html) which indicated it was not readily possible then.

I am stuck in the middle of a Unicode project. I would appreciate get clues to
proceed.

Comment: Hey, why dont you copy/paste the text here instead of making us to go there? Come on!

Comment: Please don't link off-site like that. Questions posted to Stack Overflow need to be able to stand alone without requiring external links to be useful.

Comment: Had wrongly assumed that copying/pasting will not be liked. Will take care in future. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the only Ligaturizer within iText is the `ArabicLigaturizer`, I'm surprised that Devanagari works for you actually.

Please see [Bruno Lowagie's (the primary developer) post](http://www.lowagie.com/node/125) from earlier this year along with the [post that he linked to](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/83), specifically:

> None of the current iText developers understand Hindi or any other
>   Indic language, so it's very difficult for them (if not impossible) to
>   write such an IndicLigaturizer

Replace "Indic" with "Tibetan" or any other language that needs ligatures.

Comment: Thank you for the concrete inputs. Indeed Devanagari also isn't working properly (saw when I observed closely).